# How to manage the time of a cron in the BO (admin part)

Tags: symfony, cron, symfony4, cron-task

I have a symfony 4 project with some CRON manage by the Shapecode bundle and I want to manage them from the back office. Concretely I want to get the CronJob time (30 10 * * 1-5 for example) from my BO where I stored it before. Do you know a way to do so ?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not possible to achieve this with Shapecode, you should use https://github.com/jobbyphp/jobby then create a main command executed every minutes and launch your subcommande on fly like this :

```
   $jobby = new Jobby();

   foreach ($cronTasks as $cronTask) {
       $jobby->add($cronTask->getName(), [
           'command'  => $rootDir . '/../bin/console ' . $cronTask->getCommand(),
           'schedule' => $cronTask->getSchedule(),
        ]);
    }

    $jobby->run();
```